# Where should I store the password for a webservice?

Tags: javascript, passwords, client-side

I'm developing a static website that accesses a web service for some data which uses basic HTTP authentication. I'd like to ask the user for the credentials once, and use those credentials in multiple pages of the static site.

I'm trying to figure out where to store the password with reasonable security. Cookies and local storage are inherently insecure, even if I encrypt the data (the key would still be in the Javascript code). Session variables (i.e. [sessvars](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html)) seem to be even worse.

I really would like to avoid using a server for this since I don't need a server for anything else.

The only thing I could come up with is building the entire site as a single HTML page and store the password in a closured variable. Even if it's safe enough (which I doubt), it'll still require the user to enter the password each time they visit the page and therefore not ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe local storage isn't as bad as I thought it was: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050672/15109

Comment: Can't you just use a regular (server-side) session?

Comment: If you authenticate, why do you have to keep doing it for every page?

Comment: store in cookies by disguising the value or as it is